# same width for divs/ boxes in Widget-Area of Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I just wondered if there is a way to get those boxes the same width? I tried min-width inline, but nothing happens.

This is the website: http://neuronade.com/kopie-sdfsdf-3/

[image]

Comment: you can add display: block;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to declare the following rules:

```
#mk-sidebar a.btn {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

`min-width` applies to all elements but non-replaced inline elements, table rows, and row groups.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width